# Soft color change of Roundslider

Tags: html, colors, slider, transition

I would like to have a soft/smooth color change at some value points of my RoundSlider.
At the moment I have some hard color changes at the values 16, 20, 25 but that looks not very nice.

I tried to solve this with TweenLite, but I sadly did it not make to work...
Do you have any other suggestions for me how I can solve this?

It would be okay with me to have a color transition from blue to red of the values 0 - 30, because the slider should be a input element for a thermostat.

Thank you!

```js
$("#SetRoomTmpSlider").roundSlider({
        sliderType: "min-range",
        circleShape: "half-top",
        startAngle: "315",
        lineCap: "round",
        radius: 130,
        width: 20,
    
        min: 5,
        max: 30,
        
        svgMode: true,
        pathColor: "#eee",
        borderWidth: 0,
        
        startValue: 0,
        
        valueChange: function (e) {


          var color = "#0B77DD";
          var logo = document.getElementById("SetRoomTmpSlider");

          if(e.value >= 25)
          {

            color = "#ec2906";
            
          }
          else if (e.value >= 20)
          {
            color = "#EC7906";
          }
          else if (e.value >= 16)
          {
            color = "#ECB406";
          }



          $("#SetRoomTmpSlider").roundSlider({ "rangeColor": color, "tooltipColor": color });
        }
    });
    
    var sliderObj = $("#SetRoomTmpSlider").data("roundSlider");
    sliderObj.setValue(30);
```

```css
#SetRoomTmpSlider .rs-handle {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #000;
}
#SetRoomTmpSlider .rs-tooltip-text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#SetRoomTmpSlider{

  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/round-slider@1.5.1/dist/roundslider.min.js">         </script>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div id="SetRoomTmpSlider"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simplest Answer

You can try adding something like the following to your CSS to add a *smooth* transition between the colors:

```css
#SetRoomTmpSlider path {
  transition: stroke .2s linear;
}
```

---

### Alternate Solution

The above simply allows there to be a smoother transition between existing colors. However, as per your original question I also decided to make a full transition between the *cold* and *hot* values.

Only the *cold* and *hot* colors are given. The rest is calculated based on where the slider is between to two. You will miss out on things like shades of yellow/orange (*because a shift from blue to red simply passes through purple*). But I think it's a decent effect and serves as an alternative way to achieve your goal.

```js
$("#SetRoomTmpSlider").roundSlider({
  sliderType: "min-range",
  circleShape: "half-top",
  startAngle: "315",
  lineCap: "round",
  radius: 130,
  width: 20,
  min: 5,
  max: 30,
  svgMode: true,
  pathColor: "#eee",
  borderWidth: 0,
  startValue: 0,

  valueChange: function(e) {
    var color = "#0B77DD";
    var logo = document.getElementById("SetRoomTmpSlider");
    let colorRange = [
      "0B77DD",
      "EC2906"
      ],
        colorCount = 25,
        colorIntervals = [
          Math.round((parseInt(colorRange[1].substr(0,2), 16) - parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(0,2), 16)) / colorCount),
          Math.round((parseInt(colorRange[1].substr(2,2), 16) - parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(2,2), 16)) / colorCount),
          Math.round((parseInt(colorRange[1].substr(-2), 16) - parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(-2), 16)) / colorCount)
          ],
        rC = (Math.abs(parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(0,2), 16) + ((e.value - 5) * colorIntervals[0])) < 10) ? "0"+Math.abs(parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(0,2), 16) + ((e.value - 5) * colorIntervals[0])).toString(16) : (parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(0,2), 16) + ((e.value - 5) * colorIntervals[0])).toString(16),
        gC = (Math.abs(parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(2,2), 16) + ((e.value - 5) * colorIntervals[1])) < 10) ? "0"+Math.abs(parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(2,2), 16) + ((e.value - 5) * colorIntervals[1])).toString(16) : (parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(2,2), 16) + ((e.value - 5) * colorIntervals[1])).toString(16),
        bC = (Math.abs(parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(-2), 16) + ((e.value - 5) * colorIntervals[2])) < 10) ? "0"+Math.abs(parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(-2), 16) + ((e.value - 5) * colorIntervals[2])).toString(16) : (parseInt(colorRange[0].substr(-2), 16) + ((e.value - 5) * colorIntervals[2])).toString(16);

    color = "#" + rC + gC + bC;
          
    $("#SetRoomTmpSlider").roundSlider({ "rangeColor": color, "tooltipColor": color });
  }
});

var sliderObj = $("#SetRoomTmpSlider").data("roundSlider");
sliderObj.setValue(30);
```

```css
#SetRoomTmpSlider .rs-handle {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #000;
}
#SetRoomTmpSlider .rs-tooltip-text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#SetRoomTmpSlider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/round-slider@1.5.1/dist/roundslider.min.js"></script>
<div id="SetRoomTmpSlider"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I was looking for :) Both solutions would work, but I will go with your second suggestion. In the next time I will have to get some information about how to mix some colors like in your solution.